# Remove scrollbar in mikepenz Material Drawer

Tags: android, xml, scrollbar, navigation-drawer

I use mikepenz Material Drawer and it's awesome, but I want to remove vertical scrollbar. I found nothing in Google. How can I do this?

[image: Screenshot].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get the reference to the `RecyclerView` from the result `Drawer` object.

```
result.getRecyclerView()
```

Afterwards you can easily alter it's behavior. Like disabling the **ScrollBar**

```
result.getRecyclerView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

(That's for version 4.6.4 of the MaterialDrawer)